# Maven run all tests from a package

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, junit, automated-tests

I have difficulties to run all tests from a package with `mvn` command. I have tried solution recommended on stackoverflow:  `mvn '-Dtest=de.mypackage.*Test'` test
but with no success.

Everything is fine with executing specific class or tests but I don't have success with running all tests from the package. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
mvn test -Dtest="de.mypackage.*Test"
```

or

```
mvn test -Dtest="de.mypackage.**"
```

If you want to include subpackages:

```
mvn test '-Dtest=de.mypackage.**.*Test'
```

Comment: This one works for me : mvn test -Dtest="de.mypackage.**"   Thank you! @Oboe

Comment: The first is for a _specific package_, the second and third are for _sub-packages_